# Groovy, troubles with the range operator

Tags: groovy, operators, range

I wrote a method in Groovy using the range operator in order to execute the same code multiple times:

```
/**
 * Prints the {@code files} {@code copyCount} times using 
 * {@code printService}.
 * <p>
 * Exceptions may be thrown.
 * @param printService Print service
 * @param files List of {@code File} objects
 * @param copyCount Number of copies to print
 */
private static void printJob(
        PrintService printService, 
        List<File> files, 
        int copyCount) {

    // No multiple copy support for PS files, must do it manually
    for ( i in 1..copyCount ) {
        // Print files
    }
}
```

This method did not pass unit testing as it badly fails when `copyCount` is 0.

I searched [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections#Collections-Collections-Ranges) and it seems that Groovy implements ranges like a "list of sequential values". As I understand, a range does not represent a representation of an interval of integers since it also has the notion of order embedded.

In Groovy `a..b` is not the set of integers x such that `a <= x <= b`.

In Groovy `a..b` is the representation of the enumeration `u: [0,|b-a|] -> [a..b]` defined as: `u(0) = a`, for all `i` in `[1,|b-a|]`, `u(i) = u(i-1) + sgn(b-a)`

Now I can fix my code:

```
    if (copyCount > 0) for ( i in 1..copyCount ) {
        // Print files
    }
```

Also in Groovy `a..<b` is the representation of the enumeration `u: [0,|b-a|-1] -> [a..b-1]` defined as: `u(0) = a`, for all `i` in `[1,|b-a|-1]`, `u(i) = u(i-1) + sgn(b-a)`

I noticed that the code below is also working for `copyCount` positive or zero:

```
    for ( i in 0..<copyCount ) {
        // Print files
    }
```

Still, if I can choose a solution where damages are minimized in case of inconsistency (say `copyCount` is -200, I may get 200 prints)...

```
    0.step(copyCount, 1) {
        // Print files
    }
```

At least with this solution I get a `GroovyRuntimeException: Infinite loop` in case of a negative `copyCount`. It is groovy but not very pretty and I feel like I’m playing with fire.

There is also this solution, but I find it ugly.

```
    for ( i in 0..<[0,n].max() ) {
        // Print files
    }
```

Therefore, in this case, I think the best is to avoid using the range operator, because it may be confusing for developers that are used to Perl, Ruby or Mathematics, or French (there is no word for this definition of range in French, we would just say "intervalle" for a range)... I also found it safer in case of inconsistency. Still, it is not so groovy.

```
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= copyCount ; i++ ) {
        // Print files
    }
```

Why does the range operator in Groovy is so complicated? As I see it, the fact that the step is "magically" determined and that we can’t force it (like in Ruby) is a big flaw in this implementation. Am I the only one who was ever troubled by this (two prints instead of none, it would have been a bad bug ^^ )? Did I miss something? Is there any practical case where it is required for a range to revert order when the higher bound gets lower than the lower bound? Am I being too picky?

Comment: What about `copyCount.times { ... }`? No iterations for negative numbers.

Comment: And this is groovy! Thanks hsan!